# How to combine multiple SUM in one Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have query like this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(ss.rank) as group_sum 
FROM Standard s, s.SubStandard ss 
GROUP BY s.id
```

The problem is I want to have `SUM(s.rank) as total_rank` in this query, how is this possible?

Comment: Please, provide more info about the tables (fields, data and relationships between them)

Comment: this is my tables: Standard (id, title, rank), SubStandard(id, title, rank, standard_id)

Comment: @samra You have 2 ranks one in each table... the sum of what rank do you want? How are those ranks related to each other?

Comment: I want both of them, I want sum of standard rank (the result should be one number) and sum of substandard rank group by standard_id (the result should be an array of numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Just Try:

SELECT *, SUM(ss.rank) as group_sum ,SUM(s.rank) as total_rank
FROM Standard s, s.SubStandard ss on s.id=ss.sid  // => replace with actual column
GROUPBY s.id
```

if different group by then please use `union`.

Answer (score 1):

List your individual columns (instead of *).

`SELECT SUM(s.rank) as total_rank, s.id, s.foo, s.bar, SUM(ss.rank) as group_sum
FROM standard s...`

I would suggest altering your JOIN, too.

`... LEFT JOIN substandard ss ON s.id = ss.standard`

or something similar.

Comment: the problem is I dont konw how combine two SUM with different GROUP BY in one query!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're looking for but this might help:

```
select s.id, s.title, sum(ss.rank) as group_sum from standard s
join subStandard ss
on s.id = ss.standard_id
group by s.id, s.title
```